# Use parameters in Symfonybundle in service class

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I have Symfony bundle called upload images:

I want to use parameters in my bundle in my class.

This is my parameter file:

```
upload-images:
             image:
                  crop_size: 300
```

My files:

Configuration.php

```
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder('upload-images');

        $treeBuilder->getRootNode()
                ->children()
                    ->arrayNode('image')
                        ->children()
                            ->integerNode('save_original')->end()
                            ->scalarNode('crop_size')->end()
                        ->end()
                    ->end() // twitter
                ->end();
        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

UploadImagesExtension.php

```
class UploadImagesExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(dirname(__DIR__).'/Resources'));
        $loader->load('services.yaml');

        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
    }
}
```

And final my service class:

Rotate.php

And in this class I want the parameter: crop_size

I tried the ParameterBagInterface:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;

class Rotate
{
    private $params;

    public function __construct(ParameterBagInterface $params)
    {
        $this->params = $params;
    }

    public function Rotate()
    {
        $cropSize = $params->get('crop_size');
    }

}
```

UserController.php

```
use verzeilberg\UploadImagesBundle\Service\Rotate;

class UserController extends AbstractController
{

    /** @var UserProfileService */
    private $service;

    private $userService;


    public function __construct(
        UserProfileService $service,
        UserService $userService
    ) {
        $this->service = $service;
        $this->userService = $userService;
    }

    /**
     * @param UserInterface $user
     * @return Response
     */
    public function profile(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $rotate = new Rotate();

        $rotate->Rotate();
.....



...
}

Getting this error:
```

Too few arguments to function verzeilberg\UploadImagesBundle\Service\Rotate::__construct(), 0 passed in /home/vagrant/projects/diabetigraph-dev/src/Controller/User/UserController.php on line 62 and exactly 1 expected

```
I have search for a solution. But did not came accross the right one.
```

Comment: What's your exact question about all this? What keeps you from injecting the parameters in the class?

Comment: I keep getting error's so I thought mabey my approach is wrong. I tried a couple of things but keep getting the error 'Too few arguments passed...

Comment: Why not share these errors?

Comment: Edited the post

Comment: Plpease share more details. There's a class given in that error message - what does UserController.php contain on line 62?

Comment: edited the post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the latest edit, the error is pretty obvious: if you want to use dependency injection, you have to use it. Calling `$rotate = new Rotate();` without any constructor parameters will fail, as Symfony cannot inject them for you.

Instead, inject it through the action:

```
public function profile(UserInterface $user, Rotate $rotate)
```

... this will use Symfony's container and inject the `ParameterBagInterface`, if you have enabled autowiring. If not, you have to write the proper service definitions to get this done

Comment: I have autowire on. And getting this error: Cannot autowire argument $rotate of "App\Controller\User\UserController::profile()": it references class "verzeilberg\UploadImagesBundle\Service\Rotate" but no such service exists.

Comment: Sounds like you're missing the proper import?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? I do import the file with: use verzeilberg\UploadImagesBundle\Service\Rotate;

Comment: ....and that class uses that namespace, and is placed at the proper path? Then it’s time to provide all code such that others can reproduce your Problem

Comment: Solved the problem: when I added this code to service.yaml it fixed the problem:     verzeilberg\UploadImagesBundle\Service\Rotate:
        autowire: true

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is not directly related to your question.

Either it is an autowiring issue, or maybe you are trying to instanciate the service manually? Please share what you are doing here: `UserController.php on line 62`

Anyway, to answer your question:

To access the parameters from the parameter bag you will have to set them in the extension.

`$container->setParameter('my_bundle.config', $config);`

Also, injecting the whole ParameterBag is fine for a project, but should be avoided for a bundle.

Use the DI config to inject just your parameter, OR make your extension implement `CompilerPassInterface`, and override the definition there. (It may be overkill for such a simple task)

Comment: You are trying to instanciate it yourself. Use the DIC. public function profile(UserInterface $user, Rotate $rotate)